# Surface cleaning on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cleaning

Can one, on Shabbat, spritz a surface that is dirty with a cleaning solution and then wipe it down with pre-torn paper towel? Would this be considered saturating?

Comment: Shevy, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you get answers with great information, and that you consult your rabbi regarding what you should actually do. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Shevy, is your only concern about saturating, or are you asking if it is permissible? Depending on the substance being cleaned and the agent being used, it could (potentially) also raise other issues.

Comment: @SethJ, I think the question clearly asks whether this activity is permitted, with the question about saturation, in particular, being a speculative sub-question.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Previously I had written here that spritzing is the subject of a dispute (that according to Shulchan Aruch Harav ([OC 319:29](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25073&st=&pgnum=561)) it would appear that there would be a problem because of *zoreh* (winnowing), and according to Mishnah Berurah ([OC 319:67](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=286)), it would appear that it is permitted.</sup>

<sup>However, it has since been pointed out to me that there is a fundamental difference between spritzing and the case of spitting to the wind. The (potential) issue of spitting is not because of splitting up the spit into many parts, otherwise it would be forbidden even if there is no wind, or indoors. Rather the issue is that the **wind** will split it up, which doesn't apply when there's no wind, and and likewise indoors. Therefore, there would be **no issue with with spritzing on *Shabbos***.</sup>

As far as cleaning dirty surfaces, *Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* (12:40) writes:

(*[translated](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50712) by [msh210](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/170/msh210)*)

> A table not covered with a tablecloth, and likewise a kitchen counter: if one of these got dirty, then the rule is:
>
> If the dirty area is dry, one may clean it with a dry rag of any material, and may even rub with the dry rag in order to remove the food leftovers that are stuck. But it's impermissible to clean it with a damp or wet rag, as such use will perforce lead to squeezing out.
>
> If the table or counter is damp, one may clean it with a nonabsorbent rag of synthetic material. He may, for the purpose of cleaning, even pour water on the table or counter, rub the dirt from it with his hand or a synthetic nonabsorbent rag, and even use a squeegee designated for [cleaning such surfaces]. But he should not clean the damp table or damp counter with a regular rag, even if [the latter] is dry.